# Issue with CSS Card Flip

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having an odd issue with my css card flip code. The card isn't flipping until I move my mouse off of the card. Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

Thanks in advance.

http://www.whitehotstaging.com/cb/

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code there. Also, instead of putting the whole code, add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: To re-iterate what @GalaxyCat105 said. Don't give us an entire web page to debug. Just enough code to replicate the issue.

Comment: Nobody can explain or fix the code that he/she didn't see. Please make sure to attach your relevant code in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 4 states:

1. not flipped, not hovered (no css)
2. not flipped, hovered
3. flipped, not hovered
4. flipped, hovered

The cause of your problem is that your hover-class is overriding your flip-class, [by being more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

```
/* this covers state 2 & 4, and wins both */
.flipper:hover {  
    transform: rotateY(-20deg);
}

/* this covers state 3 & 4, but loses 4 to the rule above */
.flipped {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

The first selector is more specific and wins.

You could fix it by adding an even more specific selector for the "flipped and hovered" state, like:

```
.flipped:hover {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Or you could exlude state 4 from the first rule:

```
.flipper:not(.flipped):hover {  
    transform: rotateY(-20deg);
}
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed. Thanks so much for your help. I was so frustrated I can't see the css correctly.